# javascript string length compare

Tags: javascript

I want to check the size of the string entered in a text box.
what am I missing?

```
var com = document.getElementById("comment").value;
if(com.lenght <= 100){
 alert("good");
} else {
 alert("bad");
}
```

Comment: javascrept is frustrating!

Comment: spilling is frustrating!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try changing lenght to length.

Comment: Why not comparing the string length without the length attribute? Seems not to work..

Answer (score 4):

misspelled `lenght` - should be `length`

Answer (score 3):

It is written length not lenght.

Answer (score 3):

Mis-spelling:

```
if(com.lenght <= 100){
```

use this:

```
if(com.length <= 100){
```